# Верстка 2-х блоков с 100% шириной в контейнере

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Господа, помогайте, не получается без костылей, сверстать блоки такого типа:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Верстка должна быть адаптивной, не знаю как без костылей (а именно без position: absolute или наезжающих друг на друга блоков) сверстать оранжевый и синий блок в .container, что бы их края были на всю ширину браузера, но при этом контент в этих блоках не выходил за пределы контейнера.

Answer (score 2):

Пример

```css
.bg {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255, 69, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(255, 69, 0, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 50%, rgba(0, 0, 255, 1) 100%);
}

.bg .container {
  padding-top: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
  color: #fff;
  border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="bg">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-6">Left</div>
      <div class="col-xs-6 text-right">Right</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```